# Delphi and Firebird - Error: “Attempt to reopen a open cursor”

Tags: delphi, firebird

In a Data Module I put a SQLDataSet and will be for the SQLConnection. In the "CommandText" property I'm using the line:

```
select * from tblusers
```

When changing the "Active" property of SQLDataSet, it returns the error "Attempt to reopen an open cursor" or "unknown ISC error 0". The latter occurs once, on the first attempt. I'm using Delphi Rio 10.3 and Firebird 3.0 Dialect 3.

Comment: Didn't you post this q this morning and @MarkRotteveel made a comment about the likely cause?  In any case, you need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In the future, please edit your existing question instead of deleting your old and reposting a new question. In any case, as I said, this would indicate that you (or this component) is executing the query twice without closing the cursor between executes.

Comment: `TSQLDataSet` is part of Database Express suite, that Borland was designing to fit both native and DotNet environments, and that has partially-closed sources. At least in Delphi XE2 DBX queries were uni-directional and one has to use `TClientDataSet` or any other caching in-memory dataset to scroll back and forth if needed. There was also a bug that unless explicit transaction was started the `TSQLQuery` would open a separate short-lived transaction for every fethcing every blob column in every row of the query, if any. That said, none of those would expliain "attempt to re-open" error

Comment: As of recently, after Embarcadero purchased AnyDAC (FireDAC now) DBX (design of early 2000-s) is largely considered obsolete, i wonder if it still has lot of maintenance. I also wonder if "Firebird" or "Interbase" driver is used. Because ZERO is the code for no-error, so the very text "unknown ISC error 0" is crazy. I suspect there are some complex indirect activities going on either in Firebird (like calling Stored Procedures or Finctions) or in Delphi (like using master-detail table chains or "db-aware" visual components or complex code in "db-access" components .OnXXXX" event handlers)

Comment: For example i saw all kinds of unexpected errors when dealing with one very convoluted legacy code, that started in BDE time and later was moved to DBX TSQLQuery. It had all kinds of db-aware visuals and master-detail links over CDS caches and it used tricks like sending master table object as a value for a virtual column in a detail CDS table - for the sake of "db-aware" visuals automation. I failed to make that spaghetti work in all edge cases and had to axe it to pieces and make them work with less automation and more of manual control.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help, I went back to Firebird 2.5 and the connection is working normally. I no longer get an error message from SQLDataSet, I believe there must be some incompatibility with the new Firebird 3 Library

Comment: Did you go back to the Firebird 2.5 client library, or to the Firebird 2.5 server? Which exact version of the Firebird 3 client library and Firebird 3 server were you using?

Answer (score 0):

I went back to Firebird 2.5 and I didn't get the error with SQLDataSet anymore, the connections went back to normal. I believe there is some incompatibility with the new Firebird 3 Library.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.  However, bearing in mind that the whole point of SO is that answers help **future** readers, you should still edit your q to incluse a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)